# How to use Spotify API calling as a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my React App I'm using code below to get access token. This code give me object with token, but if use it as component `<GetToken />` it doesn't return me token in console.

```
//This variant return me token
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const clientId = '*SpotifyId*';
const secretId = '*SpotifySecretCode*' ;

const App = () => {
  
  const GetToken = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
      var requestParam = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${secretId}`,
        }
      async function access_token() {
        const response = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', requestParam);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data.access_token);
      }
      access_token()
    }, [])
  };
  GetToken()
}
```

```
//This one doesn't return token
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { GetToken } from './components/GetToken';

const clientId = '*SpotifyId*';
const secretId = '*SpotifySecretCode*' ;

const App = () => {
  <GetToken />
}
```

How to change this code to use GetToken as a component?

Answer (score 0):

i thing you need to make is as a hook not as a component

create a file name it useToken.js

```
import React,{useEffect } from 'react';

useToken = ()=>{
  var requestParam = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${secretId}`,
        }
    useEffect(() => {
    
      async function access_token() {
        const response = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', requestParam);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data.access_token);
      }
      access_token()
    }, [])
}
```